# Why Drinking alcohol took so long to ban

Tags: halal-haram

Drinking alcohol is a great sin in Islam. So why did it take so long to ban it fully? Why was it not banned straight away?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it was banned straight away, it would be more difficult for people to obey. The way it was done was first it was said there is some good and some bad in it, then that there is more bad than good, and it was forbidden. When it was forbidden, the people instantly obeyed, because it was a gradual process.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is mother of all evils as Our prophet Mohammed SAW told us in hadith and who drink it ..he does great sin ..
The people in that time were drinking it and it found in every home ..every where ,so It is very hard when say to one get used to drink something  Habitual or addicted by straight way and say to him stop ..it is from mercy of Islam make it in levels and gradual process for make all can stop it ..also in that time the believing in Allah and msg of Islam was not strong ..they were anew muslims so they need to time to make their faith stronger so when Allah ban it they broke it and almadynah had rivers from alcohol